# I change the folder ICON to a red square after I finish. GONE

Tags: windows-10

I repair and convert old books into EPUB format. I have done this for 7 years and when I have completed a book, I changed the folder icon in EACH folder to a red square, signifying completion.
When I converted to windows 10 ALL the folders reverted to the default folder ICON. Can I bring those back in a group, or will I have to redo EACH folder icon again? the trouble is that I can't see the folders that are finished, as finished, because they ALL are reset to default.
Windows 10 21H2

Comment: I can tell you what >I< do.  I enable the Explorer's "Show encrypted or compressed NTFS  folders in color" option.  Then when I "mark" something, I right click and compress it turning it blue.  Explorer can't lose the setting because of a desktop.ini or registry entry.

Answer (score 0):

Its easy in windows.

1. Open the parent Folder
2. Multi-select the folders in question
3. Right Click - Properties
4. Select Customize Tab
5. In the last groupbox, Press <kbd>Change Icons</kbd> button
6. Select the Icon